# Check box refresh not working when Activity not reloaded - Android

Tags: android, database, android-activity

I have created an activity that refresh quotes when the user clicks a button. Within the same activity there is a check box which the users can click if they like the quote.

Everything works perfectly apart from the check box. When the user clicks they like the quote, I want that check box checked. This only happens when the user moves away from the activity and returns at a later stage.

However when the user stays within the activity and returns to the quote, the old state is shown instead of the users preference.

The check box is configured from the values even in the database, if the value is 1, the check box should be ticked, if not, check box should be clear.

The code is shown below:

When the user clicks the next button, the following code is executed:

```
Button nextGenerateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next_quotes);
nextGenerateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String nextQuote = myDbHelper.getnextQuote();
        setQuoteDisplay(nextQuote);
        btn_favorite.setChecked(myDbHelper.getFavouriteCheckBoxValue());

    }
});
```

The button retrieves the next quote and the getFavouriteCheckBoxValue() confirms whether the favourite column is marked in the database and either returns a true of false which sets the check box value.

```
public boolean getFavouriteCheckBoxValue()
    {
        int laballedFavourite = cursor.getInt(0);

        if(laballedFavourite == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

if the user likes the quote, the code executes the addFavourite() which updates the table where the favourite column will be modified on one.

```
btn_favorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        if(isChecked == true)
        {
            myDbHelper.addFavourite();
        }

        if(isChecked == false)
        {
            myDbHelper.removeFavourite();
        }
    }
});


public void addFavourite()
{
    ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
    vals.put("favouriteQuote", 1);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, vals, "columnId = " + cursor.getInt(1), null);
}
```

Again this only works perfectly when I resume the quote activity and not when I am currently live in the quote activity.

Hope this makes sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refreshing cursor solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh your checkbox to see the changement because you made a changement in you db but not on the UI. You need to observe the db and refresh the checkbox after a modification.

Comment: The btn_favorite.setChecked(myDbHelper.getFavouriteCheckBoxValue()); is executed on the next and back buttons but the check box is not refreshed, only when the activity is refreshed.

Comment: For that you need to recreate a cursor before get the value in the db.